# How to override default user profile fields in drupal 7 ising form API?

Tags: forms, overriding, drupal-7, user-profile

I'd like to know how to override/change the default fields in user profile such as: button Save, name, timezone etc.
I'd like to alter, delete('cause i don't need them)  some of them.
To alter the user profile i use the hook: `hook_form_alter`  using which i managed to add my own fieldds to user profile. But now i want to alter the default fields. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with the `hook_form_alter`, though it is better to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`!

To be able to alter the form you need to know the structure of the arrays, the easiest way to get to know this is by installing the Devel module. Then you can view the structure by placing `dpm($form);` inside your alter function.

You can use this function on your custom **module** or in your **theme** (in `template.php` file).

Usually user profile form_id is `user_profile_form`. A simple example would be:

```
    function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
      $form['timezone']['#access'] = FALSE; //remove the "timezone" field from the form (default value is still saved)
      $form['field_somefield']['#weight'] = -50; //move the field up
      $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Add this content now'); //change the submit button text
    }
```

For a good tutorial see the Lullabot tutorial [here](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) (is for drupal 6 but works the same way for d7!).

API: [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)